# How can I correctly code my implementation of a stack in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement, stack, do-while

I'm trying to implement a stack using an array, and here is my code so far:

```
include <stdio.h>
int stack[100], top, n = 3;
void push();
void pop();
void show();

void main(){
    top = -1;
    int ch;
    printf("1 = push, 2 = pop, 3 = display, 4 = exit \n");
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    do {
        switch(ch){
            case 1:
            push();
            break;
            
            case 2:
            pop();
            break;
            
            case 3:
            show();
            break;
            
            case 4:
            printf("Exited the stack");
            break;
            
            default:
            printf("Non existant number");
            break;
            
            
        }
    } while (ch != 4);
}

void push(){
    int value;
    if (top > n){
        printf("Stack Overflow");
    } else {
        printf("Add number to stack: ");
        scanf("%d", value);
        top++;
        stack[top] = value;
    
    }
}
void pop(){
    if (top < 0){
        printf("Stack Underflow");
    } else {
        top--;
    }
}
void show(){
    int i;
    for (i = top; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%d", stack[i]);
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code and enter 1, which is to `push` a value into the stack, instead of breaking the process after adding the value, my code keeps on asking to add a new value repeatedly until a stack overflow occurs.

I thought that adding a `break` statement after calling `push` in the switch case would break the function and ask to input a new number again, but in my current program, its not doing that.

What should I change in my code?

Comment: You should be getting a fat warning from `scanf("%d", value);`, which is wrong. That argument should be `&value`. Unrelated, don't. intermix your UX actions with your stack operations. They have near-nothing to do with each other. Code a programmatic stack, programmatically test it thoroughly, *then* code a UX that uses that well-tested implementation for whatever task you had in mind.

Comment: `printf("1 = push, 2 = pop, 3 = display, 4 = exit \n");
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);` shal be **inside** the `do` loop so that you read in a new command

Comment: And... `scanf("%d", &ch);` should be written as: `if (scanf("%d", &ch) != 1) { // No int received. Add error handling here }`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
include <stdio.h>
int stack[100], top, n = 3;
void push();
void pop();
void show();

void main(){
    top = -1;
    int ch;
    printf("1 = push, 2 = pop, 3 = display, 4 = exit \n");
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    do {
        switch(ch){
            case 1:
            push();
            break;
            
            case 2:
            pop();
            break;
            
            case 3:
            show();
            break;
            
            case 4:
            printf("Exited the stack");
            break;
            
            default:
            printf("Non existant number");
            break;
            
        }
        
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        
        
    } while (ch != 4);
}

void push(){
    int value;
    if (top == n){
        printf("Stack Overflow");
    } else {
        printf("Add number to stack: ");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        top++;
        stack[top] = value;
    
    }
}
void pop(){
    if (top < 0){
        printf("Stack Underflow");
    } else {
        top--;
    }
}
void show(){
    int i;
    for (i = top; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%d", stack[i]);
    }
}
```

Here I have changed a few parts in your code. first I have added `scanf` after the switch statement to get the number from the user end. Then I changed the `scanf("%d", &value);` inside the `push` function. because in your code not passing the address of value to `scanf`. Therefor value remains uninitialized. Finally, if condition inside the `push` function changed to check `top` value is equal to `n`